# How to see the values of a keras layer's variables' slots

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

Using keras (tf2), I'm writing my own optimiser. In this optimiser, I keep track of the moving average of the squares of all the weights, and of all the gradients. I store these in so-called *slots*, created as follows:

```
    def _create_slots(self, var_list):
        # Separate for-loops required for some reason
        for var in var_list:
            self.add_slot(var, 'squared_gradient_ma', initializer="zeros")
        for var in var_list:
            self.add_slot(var, 'squared_param_ma', initializer="zeros")
```

I update these in the `_resource_apply_dense` method, as follows:

```
    def _resource_apply_dense(self, grad, var):
        squared_gradient_ma = self.get_slot(var, 'squared_gradient_ma')
        squared_param_ma = self.get_slot(var, 'squared_param_ma')
        ma_decay = 1 / 1000000

        new_squared_gradient_ma = state_ops.assign(
            squared_gradient_ma,
            (1.0 - ma_decay) * squared_gradient_ma + ma_decay * math_ops.square(grad),
            use_locking=self._use_locking,
            )
        
        new_squared_param_ma = state_ops.assign(
            squared_param_ma,
            (1.0 - ma_decay) * squared_param_ma + ma_decay * math_ops.square(var),
            use_locking=self._use_locking,
            )
```

(Naturally, there's also code to update the actual weights, not shown.)

This makes it so that these two moving averages are updated on every training batch.

Now, at the end of training, I can inspect the weights that the model learned, by calling `layer.get_weights()`. Is there a similar thing I can call to see the values of these two slots that I made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your optimizer is subclassed from `tf.keras.optimizers.Optimizer`, and that you are training with `model.fit`, then you can access the optimizer weights with:

```
model.optimizer.get_weights()
```